# hide/disable close icon in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to hide or disable close icon of pop up window . i have close button in form which will clse the the window using self.close().How i can do it in javac=script. i tried with toolbar=no in window.open, but it doesnt work. Is there any other method to do the same?

Comment: I don't think you can, that is an OS + browser function to always include a close button. Maybe you can with a JS library...

Comment: I wouldn't really recommend doing this.  Of course it's your design, but from the user's perspective it would suck if you couldn't close a window.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that via Javascript because the close button is a component from the user's operating system.  (Javascript can't tell the OS how to behave, it only can work with the browser.)

Comment: Technically on most operating systems the browser could request the operating system to disable the close button.

Comment: Yes, but Javascript couldn't do that (I hope).  Updated anyway to something hopefully more accurate.

Comment: You can thank us by givin' some of your good good lovin (or a +1, or an accept)...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable the close button of a browser window, even if it's a popup. Imagine advertisements that couldn't close. It just has too much potential to be abused.